# How to create a web page that has similar style to m.facebook.com

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a web page that have some animations similar to m.facebook.com

You can notice that when we try to click on a Navigation as shown below, an animation like thing appears from the left side of the page that displays User Activities

[image]

How can we create such similar pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**jPanelMenu**](http://jpanelmenu.com/) I hope this is what you are looking for!

You can animate it as well, read the document [here](http://jpanelmenu.com/#options).